# Why does readFile split ; and readFileSync not?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string, buffer

Why does fs.**readFile** split up `;` and **readFileSync** not, or do both of them do it? But how does it come that the output below is different?

Content of readTesting.txt:

```
Entry1,Entry2,Entry3;2Entry1,2Entry2,2Entry3;3Entry1,3Entry2,3Entry3
```

```
fs.readFile("./readTesting.txt", "utf8", function (err, data) {
                console.log(data)
});
```

This is the log from JSON.stringify without utf8 encoding:

```
{"type":"Buffer","data":[69,110,116,114,121,49,44,69,110,116,114,121,50,44,69,110,116,114,121,51,59,50,69,110,116,114,121,49,44,50,69,110,116,114,121,50,44,50,69,110,116,114,121,51,59,51,69,110,116,114,121,49,44,51,69,110,116,114,121,50,44,51,69,110,116,114,121,51]}
```

<strike>Looking at that, 44 is the , so the semicolon is not really split up but when using it together with console.log(data) it splits it up.
And there is no sight of semicolon.</strike>

So it seems both of them split the semicolon, because I can't find any 59 in that. And 59 equals the semicolon. So how does this work?

This is the console log with utf8 and **readFile**:

```
[ 'Entry1,Entry2,Entry3',
  '2Entry1,2Entry2,2Entry3',
  '3Entry1,3Entry2,3Entry3' ]
```

This is the log without any encoding and readFileSync:

```
<Buffer 45 6e 74 72 79 31 2c 45 6e 74 72 79 32 2c 45 6e 74 72 79 33 3b 32 45 6e 74 72 79 31 2c 32 45 6e 74 72 79 32 2c 32 45 6e 74 72 79 33 3b 33 45 6e 74 72 ... >
```

this is the console log with utf8 and **readFileSync**:

```
Entry1,Entry2,Entry3;2Entry1,2Entry2,2Entry3;3Entry1,3Entry2,3Entry3
```

note that [ ] is not to see there, guess the ones before were in an array.
Also how does it show the semicolon if in the buffer `59` wasn't to find anywhere.

Also, the buffer from the readFileSync is not structured the same.

Comment: `44` is comma `,`, not semicolon `;`.

Comment: Semicolon would be `59`.

Comment: thanks, so the buffer async one splitted it even in the buffer, but somehow makes it to display it in new lines, or I think it puts them into arrays.